# Most efficient way to store shopping bag data into mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, performance

What would be the most efficient way of storing (and retrieving) session data (array) from a shopping bag into a mysql db? So that visitors get back their shopping bag content on a new visit.

All I need to store for now is: unique bag id - the product id('s) - and datetime added (to Cron old bags).

I'm thinking of storing the bagID with a simple "encryption algorithm" into a cookie.
So users could have different bags on different browsers/computers.

The options I'm thinking about:

1. Use one table and sterilize or json_encode the bag session array to store in the Data column:

   ```
   BAGS
   -----
   bagID               | data | date_added         
   int (AUTO_INCREMENT)| text | datetime
   ```
2. Use the two tables like this:

   ```
   BAGS
   -----
   bagID               | date_added         
   int (AUTO_INCREMENT)| datetime

   BAGS_CONTENT
   -----
   ID (relate to bagID)| productID (list all products in the bag)
   int                 | int(10)
   ```

I'm thinking about storing The bagID with a simple "encryption algorithm" into a cookie.
So users could have different bags on different browsers/computers.

What would be the option with the best performance? Would there be a noticeable performance difference? Or would one of the options be bad?

In option 1  would it be wise to use a Primary Key on bagID?
In option 2 would it be wise to use a Primary Key on bagID and a Foreign key on ID?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for serialize; fine and future-flexible. You might need to use other cookies than the session-id though..

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of option #2, and bagID should make a good primary key.

I have two questions:  How do you tie a user to a shopping bag?  And can a user have more than one shopping bag?

The way that I would do it, would be to add a customerID (unique identifier for each user) to the bags table.  But if a user can have only one shopping bag, then you wouldn't need bagID at all and you could just index it by customerID.

Comment: I'm thinking about storing The bagID with a simple "encryption algorithm" into a cookie.
So users could have different bags on different browsers/computers.